# autocomplete label not displaying data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, autocomplete

I am trying to autocomplete data from MySQL database with the bellow given script. It is not displaying label while it is giving correct response in developer tool network.

**JS**

```
$('#search').autocomplete({
            source: function( request, response ) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'search.php',
                    dataType: "json",
                    method: 'post',
                    data: {
                        name_startsWith: request.term,
                        type: 'type'
                    },
                    success: function( data ) {
                        response( $.map( data, function( item ) {
                                return {
                                    label: code['id'],
                                    value: code['id'],
                                    data : item
                                }
                            }));
                        }
                    });
            },
            autoFocus: true,            
            minLength: 1,
            select: function( event, ui ) {
                $('#player').val(ui.item.data.player);
                $('#marks').val(ui.item.data.marks);
            }               
        });
```

**search.php**

```
$type = $_POST['type'];
$id = $_POST['name_startsWith'];
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT id, player, marks, note FROM players where ( id LIKE '".$id."%') ");
$query->execute();
$data = array();

$i = 0;
while ($row = $query->fetch(PDO:: FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $data[$i]['id'] = $row['id'];
    $data[$i]['player'] = $row['player'];
    $data[$i]['marks'] = $row['marks'];
++$i;
}  
echo json_encode($data);
```

**Network response**

```
[{"id":"4133","player":"Sam","marks":"65"},{"id":"4955","player":"valiu","marks":"34"}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this:

```
 return {
     label: code['id'],
      value: code['id'],
      data : item
 }
```

With:

```
return {
     label: item['id'],
      value: item['id'],
      data : item
 }
```

You've wrong parameter passed.

Also from fiddle, update these and then test

change url as `url: 'https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/search.php?term=ro'` 
and change dataType as `dataType: "jsonp"`

then test

Comment: which label you want to show in autocomplete while typing?

Comment: its still not working. Can you make it work with this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/axto63hw/) .

Comment: i want player id `id` in label.

Comment: in fiddle add search.php with external server url, as direct calling `search.php` won't work with ajax.

Comment: using http://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/autocomplete/search.php?term=ro as an external server url. this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/axto63hw/2/) still not working.

Comment: I've updated code above with some changes that requires in fiddle example that you've provided.